# What is the Time Complexity for the 3 nested loops below?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Here's the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to evaluate the Time complexity in Big-O notation of the nested loops above.

Is it just `O(n) * O(n) * O(n) + O(1)` to make `O(n^3)`? Or is there more to it?

Comment: The most inner loop is executed in quadratic time (not constant), hence it should be `O(n) * O(n^2) * O(n^2)` = `O(n^5)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most inner loop is executed in quadratic time (not constant), hence it should be `O(n) * O(n^2) * O(n^2) = O(n^5)`.

Here are all the costs:

- Most outer loop - `O(n)`
- The second loop - `O(n^2)` for each element for the outer loop
- The most inner loop - `O(n^2)` for each element for the second loop

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) -> runs n times.
 for (int j = 0; j < n * n; j++) -> runs n² times.
  for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) -> runs n² times (k == j == n²)

n * n² * n² = n^5.
```

sum+++ is an operation of constant runtime (1) and can therefore be ignored.

Comment: The 3rd loop does not run *n^2* times but it does run *O(n^2)*. times. Better to stay formal to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yeah, formality was never my favourite... I'll leave the post as it is, I guess your comment as a hint should suffice, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The second loop isn't `O(n)`, it's `O(n^2)` by itself.